# objective-c get list of processes, their paths AND arguments

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, process

Getting the list of processes and their path is quite easy;

```
    int numberOfProcesses = proc_listpids(PROC_ALL_PIDS, 0, NULL, 0);
pid_t pids[1024];
bzero(pids, 1024);
proc_listpids(PROC_ALL_PIDS, 0, pids, sizeof(pids));
for (int i = 0; i < numberOfProcesses; ++i) {
    if (pids[i] == 0) { continue; }
    char pathBuffer[PROC_PIDPATHINFO_MAXSIZE];
    bzero(pathBuffer, PROC_PIDPATHINFO_MAXSIZE);
    proc_pidpath(pids[i], pathBuffer, sizeof(pathBuffer));

    char arguments[KERN_PROCARGS2];

    if (strlen(pathBuffer) > 0) {
        printf("path: %s\n", pathBuffer);
    }
}
```

However, I would also like to get any arguments that were used to launch these processes. I can't seem to find how to do this. Any pointers?

Comment: From a security standpoint, I sure hope not!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A pointer? The `ps` command lists them and its source is available as part of Apple's open source: [ps folder](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/adv_cmds/adv_cmds-149/ps).

Comment: When I run NSTask with /bin/ps I get a lot less processes than when I run the above code, so I'm not sure this is an option.

Comment: The ps source shows you how to get a processes arguments, use the algorithm in your code. Also does "ps -ax" really give you are shorter list than your code?

Comment: @Wesley perhaps when you were running the `ps` command, you were running it from root prompt, while when using the code, it runs under the process of your current user ID, showing only processes listed as you on the file user role? Just a hunch.

Answer (score 0):

```
./build64.sh # Build cmdline app for 64-bit Intel Mac
# Enumerate all processes running and print the argvs
./xproc --pid-enum | xargs -L1 ./xproc --cmd-from-pid
```

Calling the functions directly will be faster than running a new task.

Source code can be built for Windows, MacOS, Linux, and FreeBSD.

Feel free to borrow any portion of code you may need from it:

https://github.com/time-killer-games/xproc